# Finding the Taylor series (complex numbers)

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, taylor-expansion

I have
$$
{\frac{1}{(z+1)(z-2)}}
$$
I did
$$
{\frac{1}{(z+1)(z-2)}} = {\frac{A}{z+1}}+{\frac{B}{z-2}}
$$

and found
$A=-1/3, B=1/3$

So now I have
$$
-{\frac{1}{3}}\times {\frac{1}{z+1}}+{\frac{1}{3}}\times{\frac{1}{z-2}} = -{\frac{1}{3}} \sum(-1)^k z^k + {\frac{1}{3}} \sum(-1)^k (-{\frac{z}{2}})^k
$$

But the answer in the book is different. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the answer in the book? See that the second summation can be simplified to $\sum (z/2)^k$.

Comment: The answer in book is
$$
{\frac{1}{3}} \sum((-1)^{n+1}-2^{-n-1}) z^n
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have if $|r|<1$, then $$\frac{1}{1-r}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty r^i$$

\begin{align}
-{\frac{1}{3}}\times {\frac{1}{z+1}}+{\frac{1}{3}}\times{\frac{1}{z-2}} &=-{\frac{1}{3}} \sum(-1)^k z^k - \frac16 \times \frac{1}{1-\left( \frac{z}2\right)}
\\&= -{\frac{1}{3}} \sum(-1)^k z^k - {\frac{1}{6}} \sum ({\frac{z}{2}})^k \\
&= \frac13 \left[\sum(-1)^{k+1} z^k - {\frac{1}{2}} \sum ({\frac{z}{2}})^k \right]\\
&= \frac13 \sum\left[(-1)^{k+1}  - {2}^{-k-1} \right]z^k\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed true that$$\frac1{(z+1)(z-2)}=-\frac13\times\frac1{z+1}+\frac13\times\frac1{z-2}$$and that$$\frac1{z+1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^kz^k.$$However,$$\frac1{z-2}=-\frac1{2-z}=-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{z^k}{2^{k+1}}.$$

Comment: What formula did you use for series of $-{\frac{1}{2-z}}$?

Comment: $$\frac1{a-z}=\frac1a\times\frac1{1-\frac za}=\frac1a\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac za\right)^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{z^k}{a^{k+1}}.$$